# jquery Skillbar loading on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have some skillbar's with a jquery animation that  loads my %... but i want the animation to start once the skillbar is scrolled to within the viewport

this is my code:

//jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
            $( "data-percent" ).focus(); <--- i do try this
        },6000);
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
    <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2980b9;"><span>CSS3</span></div>
    <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #3498db;"></div>
    <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->
```

some one who can help my out??

Comment: So, to clarify, you want the animation to start once the skillbar is scrolled to within the viewport?

Comment: yes, that is exacly what i mean!!! :) i should update my question!!